# How to pass a function from a component to another component in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have 2 class components in 2 different js files. The "dish" variable is defined in one and I'm trying to use it in the second file. I'm still new to this, so I'm really not sure if I'm structuring this correctly. Could some one help?

First class component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Card,
  CardImg,
  CardImgOverlay,
  CardText,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle
} from "reactstrap";
import Dishdetail from "./DishdetailComponent";

class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedDish: null,
      details: Dishdetail
    };
  }
  onDishSelect(dish) {
    this.setState({
      selectedDish: dish
    });
  }

  renderDish(dish) {
    if (dish != null) {
      return <Dishdetail details={this.state.details} />;
    } else {
      return <div />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const menu = this.props.dishes.map(dish => {
      return (
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          <Card key={dish.id} onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
            <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
            <CardImgOverlay>
              <CardTitle> {dish.name} </CardTitle>
            </CardImgOverlay>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row"> {menu}</div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
            {this.renderDish(this.state.selectedDish)}{" "}
          </div>{" "}
        </div>{" "}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

=======================

Second code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Card,
  CardImg,
  CardImgOverlay,
  CardText,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle
} from "reactstrap";
import Menu from "./MenuComponent";

class Dishdetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dish: Menu
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <dish />
          <Card>
            <CardImg top src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
            <CardBody>
              <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
              <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dishdetail;
```

The error message I'm getting is that "dish" variable is not defined

Comment: As you are using props to send data to child no need to import parent component in child again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set `props` to `state` in child like this,

```
this.state = {
   dish: Menu
};
```

As you are passing `details` as `props` from parent component you should do this,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      dish: props.details,
    }
}
```

And you should use this state in child component like.

```
{this.state.dish}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-lrfdq?fontsize=14) - How to pass data from parent and usage in child component.

**Update**

[Your Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-9wi8c?fontsize=14) - I have corrected your code. Just make sure you pass correct details to your `Menu` component.

**Note:** This code gives you error because I don't know what `this.props.dishes` is. Ignore the error and concentrate on code only.

Comment: I've been stuck on this for a week. Thank you so much for your help!